# Legality of using official Oracle reference to create a parser?

Tags: software

[Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/index.html) is a parser generator. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm) is the official Oracle reference for PL/SQL.

If I use the information in the reference to create a PL/SQL parser, would this have any legal implications?

Since the reference is freely available to public, I initially thought not but being freely available to public might not imply that I may use the reference for however purpose.

So, would using the official Oracle reference to create a software be legal?